# WordPress count post shortcode for Taxonomy [tags]

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

**Problem**
I want to create shortcodes for my WordPress website which has a CPT => toernooi
The function for counting posts works with the following code:

```
    // Get post count for cpt
add_shortcode('toernooiencount', 'post_count');
function post_count() {
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts('toernooi');
    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
    echo $published_posts . ' ';
}
```

Now I want to create the same function for counting posts but in different taxonomies inside this same CPT. Tried to find a solution but could not find anything that worked.
The WordPress website wp_count_posts has no information on using different use cases.

**Question**
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be going with WP_Query like this:

```
$args  = array(
    'post_type'      => 'toernooi',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your_taxonomy',
            'field'    => 'slug', //('id' o 'slug')
            'terms'    => 'my_term_slug_or_id',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo "We have found {$query->post_count} posts witht the query";
```

I can't think about another solution, since wp_query internally always does "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" you will have that count w/o any further cost

Comment: Hi Diego, How would this Query work? do i attach a shortcode like my snippet above?
I just need the number that comes out of the Query. Echo $query->post_count would be enough. I would then make two snippets for each taxonomie and get the number of posts in that taxonomie and display it on the front-end.

Comment: Just store the result using wordpress base cache or transient with a custom lifetime. That would prevent the site from bloating with queries if you have multiple instances of the shortcode around the website